# opp_run error in veins 4.4 + sumo0.25 + omnet 4.6

Tags: omnet++, veins

I'm a master student beginner in simulations with omnet++.
It's my first installation of omnet + veins + sumo for IVC simulations.

I'm spend all day to solve this, without success. I really need a help of anyone.

Basically I'm receiving this error when I try run "/veins-4.4/examples/veins" example as suggested in tutorial. The error is:

```
Starting...

$ cd /local1/liborio/VehicularNetworking/workspace/veins-4.4/examples/veins
$ opp_run -r 0 -n .:../../src/veins --tkenv-image-path=../../images -l ../../src/veins-4.4 omnetpp.ini

<!> Warning: opp_run: Cannot check library ../../src/veins-4.4: ../../src/veins-4.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


<!> Error during startup: Cannot load library '../../src/veins-4.4': ../../src/veins-4.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
OMNeT++ Discrete Event Simulation  (C) 1992-2014 Andras Varga, OpenSim Ltd.
Version: 4.6, build: 141202-f785492, edition: Academic Public License -- NOT FOR COMMERCIAL USE
See the license for distribution terms and warranty disclaimer

End.

Simulation terminated with exit code: 1
Working directory: /local1/liborio/VehicularNetworking/workspace/veins-4.4/examples/veins
Command line: opp_run -r 0 -n .:../../src/veins --tkenv-image-path=../../images -l ../../src/veins-4.4 omnetpp.ini

Environment variables:
PATH=/local1/liborio/VehicularNetworking/omnetpp-4.6/bin::/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/local1/liborio/VehicularNetworking/workspace/sumo-0.25.0/bin:/local1/liborio/VehicularNetworking/omnetpp-4.6/bin:/home/liborio/Documents/Unicamp/Dropbox/Pesquisa-Mestrado/Projeto/OpenStreetMaps/osmosis-0.44/bin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/local1/liborio/VehicularNetworking/omnetpp-4.6/lib::/local1/liborio/VehicularNetworking/workspace/veins-4.4/src:
OMNETPP_IMAGE_PATH=/local1/liborio/VehicularNetworking/omnetpp-4.6/images
```

Thanks a lot for any answer.

Comment: Did you get any errors or warnings when building? Does the `veins-4.4/src` folder contain a symbolic link to `libveins.so`?

Comment: I solved the problem only changing the project folder name to "veins".

Comment: Glad you were able to solve your question. If you don't mind, could you update your answer and mark it as the correct one for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prof. @Christoph Sommer, thanks for the answer.

On the building not errors or warnings are showed.

The libveins.so is on the veins-4.4/src folder:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 liborio liborio   188 Mar 22 08:58 index.h
lrwxrwxrwx 1 liborio liborio    36 Abr 15 13:55 libveins-4.4.so -> ../out/gcc-debug/src/libveins-4.4.so
-rw-rw-r-- 1 liborio liborio 46586 Abr 14 16:44 Makefile
drwxrwxr-x 2 liborio liborio  4096 Mar 22 08:58 scripts
drwxrwxr-x 5 liborio liborio  4096 Mar 22 08:58 veins
```

I solved this problem using the terminal directly.

I launched the server with sumo-launchd.py script.

Via terminal, on the folder */examples/veins I run the commands:

Run in terminal.

```
opp_run -r 0 -u Cmdenv -n .:../../src/veins -l ../../src/libveins-4.4.so omnetpp.ini
```

Run with graphical interface.

```
opp_run -r 0 --tkenv-image-path=../../images -n .:../../src/veins -l ../../src/libveins-4.4.so omnetpp.ini
```

But it is possible only run via terminal. On the IDE de same error
occurs.

I noticed that the path showed on error:
The folder "veins-4.4", not exists on the folder "/src". The folder that exists is named "veins".

But as I do not know the effects of changing the folder name, I not do it.

I tried with version 4.3 and the same situation occurs.

Best Regards.

Comment: I solved the problem only changing the project folder name to "veins".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I solved the problem by myself. When I import the veins-4.4 into OMNeT++ 5.0, I have to make sure the folder name (listed in the IDE) is "veins", not "veins-4.4". Then the built .so file will also be named as libveins.so, instead of libveins-4.4.so.