# opp_run error in veins 5.1 & omnet 6.0pre10

Tags: omnet++, veins

I have successfully built Veins 5.1 on OMNeT++ 6.0pre10. My operating system is Windows 10.

However, when I try to run `veins/examples/veins/omnetpp.ini`, I receive the error shown below.

> <!> Error: Cannot load library '../../src//libveins.dll': can not found
> End.
> Simulation terminated with exit code: 1
> Working directory: D:/omnetpp-6.0pre10/samples/veins/examples/veins
> Command line: ../../../../bin/opp_run.exe -m -u Qtenv -n .;../../src/veins --image-path=../../images -l ../../src/veins omnetpp.ini
> Environment variables:
> PATH=;D:/omnetpp-6.0pre10/samples/veins/src;D:\omnetpp-6.0pre10\bin;D:\omnetpp-6.0pre10\tools\win64\mingw64\bin;D:\omnetpp-6.0pre10\tools\win64\usr\bin;;D:/omnetpp-6.0pre10/ide/jre/bin/client;D:/omnetpp-6.0pre10/ide/jre/bin;.;D:\omnetpp-6.0pre10\bin;D:\omnetpp-6.0pre10\tools\win64\opt\mingw64\bin;D:\omnetpp-6.0pre10\tools\win64\mingw64\bin;D:\omnetpp-6.0pre10\tools\win64\usr\local\bin;D:\omnetpp-6.0pre10\tools\win64\usr\bin;D:\omnetpp-6.0pre10\tools\win64\usr\bin;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;D:\omnetpp-6.0pre10\tools\win64\usr\bin\site_perl;D:\omnetpp-6.0pre10\tools\win64\usr\bin\vendor_perl;D:\omnetpp-6.0pre10\tools\win64\usr\bin\core_perl;D:\omnetpp-6.0pre10;
> OMNETPP_ROOT=D:/omnetpp-6.0pre10/
> OMNETPP_IMAGE_PATH=D:\omnetpp-6.0pre10\images

My folder name is just "veins".
I have seen another question about this problem at [opp_run error in veins 4.4 + sumo0.25 + omnet 4.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36633386/opp-run-error-in-veins-4-4-sumo0-25-omnet-4-6). However, this solution does not solve my problem.

Could you please help me about the problem?
I would be appreciate for any answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have installed OMNeT++ version 5.6.2 instead of 6.0. The problem has been solved.
Veins (even the latest version 5.1) is not compatible with OMNeT 6.0 on Windows 10. However, it works fine with OMNeT++ 5.6.2. (Please do not forget to rename the folder just as "veins")

Comment: Thank you for following up on this! Indeed, Veins 5.1 does not build on Microsoft Windows when using OMNeT++ 6.0pre10. Because of changes to the build system used by OMNeT++, [line 29 of the `makefrag` file](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5.1/src/makefrag#L29) needs to have `LIBS` changed to `OMNETPP_LIBS`. I have made sure to update the website to point this out.